# javascript bookmarklet with input

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am trying to create a javascript bookmarklet that will iterate values within.

Basically what I'm trying to do is input something like

```
{
"type": "collection",
"id": "home_featured_collections_7"
},
```

Then input values like current iteration is 7 and final iteration will be 10 and it would output something like

```
{
"type": "collection",
"id": "home_featured_collections_7"
},
{
"type": "collection",
"id": "home_featured_collections_8"
},
{
"type": "collection",
"id": "home_featured_collections_9"
},
{
"type": "collection",
"id": "home_featured_collections_10"
},
```

My first instinct was to have it copy the original text from the clipboard and then output to the clipboard but I couldn't figure out how to do this. I've currently set it up using prompts

```
javascript:(function(){
text=prompt("Expand Text", ""); 
current=prompt("Current Iteration", ""); 
final=prompt("Final Iteration", ""); 
return_text = "";
    for (i = current; i <= final; i++) { 
        return_text += text.replace(current, i);
    } 
prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter",return_text);}()
    );
```

But I am having a little trouble. The quotes and colon are causing trouble or at least I assume that is the case. This is my first time making a js bookmarklet so I apologize if there are better ways to do this.

Any advice would be great!

Comment: Why are you using global variables?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by global variables @gcampbell? Do you mean without including var? i.e.  var text = ....

Comment: Yes, variables declared without `var` are global.